# Regexp to check e-mail address

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to know how to use MySQL's REGEXP or RLIKE feature for the two following tasks:

> Task #1
>   Select all e-mail addresses, but only return the component after the @ and before the first . in the domain.  So say I had 3 emails in a table... bob@123.com, bill@456.com, ben@789.com I would just want it to return 3 results of 123, 456, 789.

---

> Task #2
>   When used in a WHERE clause, I would like to only match where the same part of the domain (after the @ and before the first .) meets a certain criteria.  For arguments sake, lets say this is 123, 456 or 789.

Comment: I don't think people are going to do your work for you -- I know I'm not. We're happy to help, but not do your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task #1 - there is no way to do this, MySQL can use REGEXPS only for comparision

Task #2 -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^[^@]+@(123|456|789)\\..*$'
```